# Component [livewire-tags] class not found: [LivewireTags\Components\LivewireTags]

Tags: php, laravel, package.json, laravel-livewire

I am creating my own custom composer package with Laravel Livewire. My problem is, even if I add the Livewire class in the boot function in the package service provider class, the Livewire component class is not found in the packages folder.

**Package Directory**

[image]

**LivewireTagsServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace  Zain\LivewireTags;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Livewire\Livewire;
use LivewireTags\Components\LivewireTags;



class LivewireTagsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

  public function boot()
  {
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__  .   '/routes/web.php');
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__. '/views', 'livewire-tags');
    Livewire::component('livewire-tags', LivewireTags::class);
  }

  public function register()
  {
  }

}
```

**LivewireTags.php**

```
<?php

namespace LivewireTags\Components;

use Livewire\Component;

class LivewireTags extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.livewire-tags');
    }
}
```